# IAR preprocessor: include a tons of path

Tags: embedded, workbench, iar

I need to add in iar's preprocessor a huge amount of paths!  Every path has a lot of subfolder and so on. 
I dont want to do it manually because projects i am working on are very huges and the struct of the folders may vary over time!
There is a method to automatically includes all the subfolder in a project?
i am using iar 7.80

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of project options to include subfolders of include paths with IAR.

A few alternatives to using the project options dialog:

**1. Edit the *.ewp file**

If you search for `CCIncludePath2`, you'll find entries like this

```
<option>
    <name>CCIncludePath2</name>
    <state>$PROJ_DIR$\..\include</state>
</option>
```

This means you can keep/generate a list of include paths and insert it relatively easily.

**2. Use subfolders in `#include` statements**

If you have your headers in a structure like this:

```
include
include/library1
include/library1/componentX
include/library1/componentX/buffer.h
```

If you write in your code

```
#include "library1/componentX/buffer.h"
```

Rather than

```
#include "buffer.h"
```

You can configure IAR with an include path of `include`, but don't need `include/library1/componentX`. And it means that if there's another buffer.h in your include paths, there is no ambiguity.

I prefer the second option, but it has limitations: If the files with the `#include` directives aren't within your control, you still have to specify each include path.
It also offer the benefit that if you were to change the include folder structure, you can easily do a replace-in-files on the affected headers.
The first option is not as elegant, but it can also be used where you can't change the files with the `#include` directives.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped a lo! Infact searching for some documentation regarding the .ewp file i find out that there is another way to do that! I imported an ifng file, that is very similar to the .ewp. In iar go to: Project-> add project connection ->connect using: IAR project connection.